# Black stripe over the navigation bar (AOSP)

Tags: android

I have a strange black bar (around 30 dp), which is over the navigation bar (see attached image).

It is preventing my app from fully wrapping it's view. Probably it is some system window border, which I can't yet find how to disable/resize.

It is observed in some apps, and in some it is not (which seems that applying some theme or window flag should remove it).

Here is what I've tried up to now:

- Changed app theme to a different one (e.g. @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Settings).
- Applied this in oncreate:
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
- Changed the nav bar size - it only gets smaller, but the black line stays in the same position
- Using uiautomatorviewer doesn't seem to show the view (and id) of the navigation bar at all.

Any help for removing this line would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello again and thanks for the support.
Finally I've found the issue. It was due to the api which was used (android-23). After updating to android-29, the issue is resolved. Seems that somehow theming or windowing mechanism is affected by the old api (and the app does not cover the whole screen - the rest is covered by a black background).
PS: I needed to restart the phone in order this to be applied. Killing of the app after adb push didn't apply the setting.